# Accessing controller function in Directive scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access the function defined in the controller scope from directive nested in another directive. I am using the "&" and passing the function name as the attribute to the directive, however I am still not able to reach the function in the controller scope.

Could some one correct where I am going wrong? I had spent few hours trying to find that I have to use the "&" for reaching controller scope but stuck here after whatever I did.

JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/fwR9Q/12/

Code:

```
<div ng-controller="PlayerCtrl">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="video in videos" >
<tf-video src="{{video.src}}" width="{{video.width}}" handleClick="playVideo(videoId, modeNum)" height="{{video.height}}" title="{{video.title}}"/>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('PlayerCtrl',
  function PlayerCtrl($scope,$log, trailers)
  {
     $scope.videos = trailers;
     $scope.playVideo = function(videoId, modeNum){
        alert("video Id = " + videoId + "; mode Num = " + modeNum);
        return false;
     };
  }
);

myApp.directive('tfVideo', function() {
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      src: '@',
      handleClick: '&',
      width: '@width',
      height: '@height'
    },
    template: '<a href="#" ng-click="handleClick({videoId: {{src}}, modeId: modeNum{{$parent.$index}} })"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{src}}/0.jpg" height="{{height}}" width="{{width}}"/></a>'
  };
});

myApp.factory('trailers', function(){
  var trailerVideos = [
      {
        src:"6kw1UVovByw",
        width:"324",
        height:"300"
      },
      {
        src:"uWgDVz4NEO4",
        width:"324",
        height:"300"
      }
     ];
return trailerVideos;
});
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: since all you are doing is using directive to generate a template, why do you even need isolated scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) On your directive declaration:

```
<tf-video src="{{video.src}}" width="{{video.width}}" handleClick="playVideo(videoId, modeNum)" height="{{video.height}}" title="{{video.title}}"/>
```

Since attributes use the snake-cased form.

Instead of: `handleClick=`

You want the snake cased: `handle-click=`

2) In your template:

```
 template: '<a href="#" ng-click="handleClick({videoId: {{src}}, modeId: modeNum{{$parent.$index}} })"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{src}}/0.jpg" height="{{height}}" width="{{width}}"/></a>'
```

Instead of:  `{videoId: {{src}}, modeId: modeNum{{$parent.$index}} }`

You want:  `{videoId: src, modeNum: $parent.$index }`

Since you need the "modeNum" parameter name to match between the template and the directive and you want to map directly to the variables, not expressions.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwR9Q/15/)